# Prevent layout shift on image load with css

Tags: c#, html, css, cumulative-layout-shift

I'm using `padding-bottom hack` to prevent content jump around when my images load, but it doesn't work with smaller images. Here's the code that works fine for images that take up the whole 60% of my container width:

View:

```
 decimal aspectRatio = Block.Image.Height / (decimal)Block.Image.Width;
 decimal paddingPercent = aspectRatio * 60;

 <div style="padding-bottom:@paddingPercent.ToString().Replace(',', '.')%;
     <img src="@imageUrl" />
 </div>
```

Styles:

```
 .img-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #f1f4f6;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 60%;
                
        img {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: auto;
        }
    }
```

But if I use image like 48x48, my `aspectRatio` is going to be 1, and the `paddingPercent` will be 60%, so i'm having this problem (see the last image - flag):
[image]

i'd appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

To keep using the responsive approach, you could add a condition to your code for images smaller than some set amount of pixels (for example, let's say 100px in this example)

```
decimal aspectRatio = Block.Image.Height / (decimal)Block.Image.Width;
decimal padding = aspectRatio;
string actualPadding = '';
if((decimal)Block.Image.Width > 100)
    actualPadding = (padding * 60) + '%';
else
    actualPadding = Block.Image.Height + 'px';
```

An alternative to using padding for it would be to just add the `width` and `height` attributes to your image tag. This will make the images take up the same amount of space before and after loading..

`<img src="" width="@Block.Image.Height" height="Block.Image.Width" />`

This approach assumes that the width and height of the images on your web page are same as their original width/heights.

Comment: the image height and width is in px, so it won't be responsive

Comment: i dont think I can hardcore the values like 100px width, i'd say i need to know if the image width doesn't cover 60% of the container, then apply some other portion of padding in % - this should be the formula i guess, maybe take into account the width of screen...

Comment: Then you should just use the `width` and `height` attributes and do the responsive via CSS media queries